Exclude url form OAuth2 security authentication
I have this Spring Security 6 configuration configured to work with Keycloak server:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(registry -> registry
                        .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/internal/token").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2Configurer -> oauth2Configurer.jwt(jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwt -> {
                    Map<String, Collection<String>> realmAccess = jwt.getClaim("realm_access");
                    Collection<String> roles = realmAccess.get("roles");
                    var grantedAuthorities = roles.stream()
                            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, grantedAuthorities);
                })));

        return httpSecurity.build();
  }
}

This code works well but I need to have a url configured for free access.
I tried to add .requestMatchers("/internal/token").permitAll() so that I can use it without authentication.
I get always 401 Unauthorized when I use Postman to POST a request and in logs I get:
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://locahost:4000/realms/my_realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs": locahost:4000
Looks like above configuration is not allowed. Do you know how I can properly configured this?
Do I need to add something else into above configuration? I can't find a solution here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/getting-spring-security.html which can be usefull in my case.
EDIT. Debug log when I sent manual request with Postman:
2024-06-01T15:52:49.593+03:00 DEBUG 10656 --- [platform-provider] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [PATCH /internal/token/4818a55d-8c8a-42fd-a723-78b90c0053f5 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJ.................................a4cTsvQQ
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: JSESSIONID=CBF2036B11D59E464AA25DC1AB20993F; JSESSIONID=43C0F26E2D0652B417F5F5601E939933
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.39.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: d9abc2b5-7597-4388-a034-1cc31f064fe5
Host: localhost:8134
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 31

{
    "status": "ENABLED"
}
]
2024-06-01T15:52:49.593+03:00 DEBUG 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.a.t.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor   : Cookies: Parsing b[]: JSESSIONID=CBF2036B11D59E464AA25DC1AB20993F; JSESSIONID=43C0F26E2D0652B417F5F5601E939933
2024-06-01T15:52:49.593+03:00 DEBUG 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter     :  Requested cookie session id is CBF2036B11D59E464AA25DC1AB20993F
2024-06-01T15:52:49.594+03:00 DEBUG 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request PATCH /internal/token/4818a55d-8c8a-42fd-a723-78b90c0053f5
2024-06-01T15:52:49.594+03:00 DEBUG 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
2024-06-01T15:52:49.594+03:00 DEBUG 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Not subject to any constraint
2024-06-01T15:52:49.594+03:00 DEBUG 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper   :   Returning instance
2024-06-01T15:52:49.594+03:00 TRACE 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@516d932a
2024-06-01T15:52:49.594+03:00 TRACE 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@76fece79, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@491ef90c, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@79b07ccd, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@22a05923, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@6a5c67cf, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@11932248, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@4c3663fc, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5f19da2c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@76300346, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6ae729fb, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@351623d, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@6537dc79]] (1/1)
2024-06-01T15:52:49.594+03:00 DEBUG 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing PATCH /internal/token/4818a55d-8c8a-42fd-a723-78b90c0053f5
2024-06-01T15:52:49.594+03:00 TRACE 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2024-06-01T15:52:49.594+03:00 TRACE 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2024-06-01T15:52:49.594+03:00 TRACE 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2024-06-01T15:52:49.594+03:00 TRACE 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2024-06-01T15:52:49.594+03:00 TRACE 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CorsFilter (5/12)
2024-06-01T15:52:49.595+03:00 TRACE 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/12)
2024-06-01T15:52:49.595+03:00 TRACE 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2024-06-01T15:52:49.595+03:00 TRACE 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter (7/12)
2024-06-01T15:52:49.595+03:00 TRACE 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with JwtAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
2024-06-01T15:52:49.596+03:00 DEBUG 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.s.s.oauth2.jwt.JwtTimestampValidator   : Jwt expired at 2024-05-22T23:04:30Z
2024-06-01T15:52:49.596+03:00 DEBUG 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider  : Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid
2024-06-01T15:52:49.596+03:00 TRACE 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] .s.r.w.a.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter : Failed to process authentication request

org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.InvalidBearerTokenException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Jwt expired at 2024-05-22T23:04:30Z
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:103) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:88) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtValidationException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Jwt expired at 2024-05-22T23:04:30Z
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.validateJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:193) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.decode(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:139) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:99) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    ... 63 common frames omitted


2024-06-01T15:52:49.596+03:00 DEBUG 10656 --- [platform-service] [nio-8134-exec-3] o.s.s.oauth2.jwt.JwtTimestampValidator   : Jwt expired at 2024-05-22T23:04:30Z

I see this but in my case I need not to have JWT security for /internal/token endpoint. As a second option if this is not possible I need to have a Basic ...... token security for /internal/token. Is one of these options possible?

Answered that quite a few times already
If a token is invalid (expired, bad issuer, wrong checksum, ...), a resource server filter chain will return a 401, whatever authorizeHttpRequests is set with.
Two options:

set the authorizeHttpRequests request matcher with permitAll() but do not send a token with the request
define another filter-chain with higher precedence (lower @Order), a securityMatcher to intercept the requests allowed to anonymous, and no security

the 1st option is simpler and cleaner (an OAuth2 client should not send request with junk tokens).
P.S.
Are you trying to return a token from a resource server for real? If so, I suggest that you have a closer look at OAuth2 fundamentals and recommended patterns for authorizing requests from single-page and mobile applications

I'm trying to create a authorization provider
